# jQuery image error handling for media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have images loaded depending on screen size using media queries. I would like to handle the error if any using jQuery. A text message will show when the image failed.

My code so far:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" id="notice_banner" alt="" src="css/images/banner.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p id="altText" style="display: none">
            This is a text!
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
/* xs */
img {
content:url("images/small_banner.png");
}
/* md */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
img {
    content:url("images/large_banner.png");
}
}
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("img").on("error", function() {
    $("#altText").show();
});
});
```

The problem now is that it can detect the error from the original src attribute, but not when the images are coming from media queries.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can refer this example: https://jsfiddle.net/s3du7jao/2/

Comment: @LYNK that is what I'm doing, but it's not taking the error from media queries. It works for `src` attribute within `img`, but not `@media` from CSS.

Comment: I know this comment is not answering your question but: are you sure that this is what you want to use? `content` is not fully supported outside of the pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` (afaik only Chrome supports it).

Comment: I can't find other ways to  change the `src` other than using `content` though. Do you have any suggestion or other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, `content` is not fully supported outside of the pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` (as far as I know, only Chrome supports it for any element). And on top of that, there's another problem with doing things this way: CSS errors do not trigger JS events, so if an image linked in CSS fails, JS will not detect it.

One solution would be to listen to the `resize` event, and if the window size goes through a threshold used in a media query, perform one action or another (e.g. change the `src` of the image). In this case, as the change happened within JS, you would be able to read it.

For example, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("img").on("error", function() {
    $("#altText").show();
  });

  function resizeActions() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth < 768) {
      $("#notice_banner").attr("src", "//placehold.it/100x100");
    } else if (windowWidth >= 768) {
      $("#notice_banner").attr("src", "fake-url-path");
    } // else if ...
    
  };

  // execute on load and on window resize
  $(window).resize(resizeActions);
  resizeActions();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" id="notice_banner" alt="" src="//placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p id="altText" style="display: none">
        This is a text!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks like using JS to detect window size change is the better choice compared to using CSS. Thanks!